# Making a complicated query in Django all my follows posts

Tags: python, django, orm

Imagine that:

I have "Posts", "Users", "UserFollowUser" models in a Django app...

I want to get all the POSTS from my POST model but only for people that I FOLLOW.

Every POST has a USER id of the user who is the author.

I mean, there's a register that says:

"Cris" follows "Larry"

I want to get the posts from Larry and some other people I follow.

I tried:

```
follows = UserFollowUser.objects.get(follower = request.user) #I AM request.user
posts = Post.objects.filter(user = follows.followed).order_by('-id')
```

But I can only get posts from ONE person because of the "GET" function in objects object.

Comment: If this were in SQL, I would write something like SELECT p.* FROM UserFollowsUser ufu INNER JOIN Post p on (ufu.followed = p.user_id) WHERE ufu.follower = $1;  It would be something like that in SQLAlchemy.  Is there an objects.getall() or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is get an array of user ids for your followers. Then use the [__in syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) to make a query where you are asking for all posts whose user id is in the set of user ids of your followers. The code would look something like this:

```
follower_user_ids = UserFollowUser.objects.filter(follower__user_id = request.user.id)\
                                          .values_list('follower__user_id', flat=True)\
                                          .distinct()
posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id__in=follower_user_ids)
```

*this assumes UserFollowUser.follower is a foreign key to the User table.

Comment: I think you mean followees, because the requester is the follower. I'm not sure you're using the right value in the list - that looks like it will only give the request.user.id.  I think you want your .values_list() to contain 'followed__user_id', but other than that it looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is code if you want to show posts of all users logged in user follows also your own posted posts in the feed:

```
follows_users = user.profile.follows.all()
follows_posts = Post.objects.filter(author_id__in=follows_users)
user_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
post_list = (follows_posts|user_posts).distinct().order_by('-date_posted')
```

You can always take reference for social media django clone from https://github.com/uttampatel007/nccbuddy